# Shiny : Make edits persist across pages in editable datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shinyapps

I have an editable datatable which is paginated as follows :

```
d1 = file.df
output$file.df_data<-DT::renderDataTable(
      d1,selection = 'none', editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = c(which(names(d1) != "product_type")-1))), 
      rownames = FALSE,
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      
      options = list(
        paging = TRUE,
        searching = TRUE,
        fixedColumns = TRUE,
        autoWidth = TRUE,
        ordering = TRUE,
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = c('csv', 'excel')
      ),
      
      class = "display"
    )
```

When I make an edit on the current page, move to some other page, and then return to the previous page the edits that I had made on the page disappear. How can I make the edits persist across the pages?

Following is the code I am using to observe edits-

```
observeEvent(input$file.df_data_cell_edit, {
      d1[input$file.df_data_cell_edit$row,input$file.df_data_cell_edit$col+1] <<- input$file.df_data_cell_edit$value
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a proxy and the `editData` function:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  dat <- iris
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, editable = TRUE)
  })
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("dtable")
  
  observeEvent(input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["dtable_cell_edit"]]
    dat <<- editData(dat, info, proxy)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```